# pandas groupby and mean aggregation on more columns

Tags: pandas

I can't find any way to get the output from my input. I want to group by user and question, (but this question information is already in the answer columns, because it's NaN in the Question is not related to the given Answer, see below) and get the means for each Answer column.

Q stands for Question, A stands for Answer

Input:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'userid':[11,11,11,12,13,13],
        'Q':['Q1','Q2','Q1','Q3','Q1','Q1'],
        'A1':[1,np.NaN,0,np.NaN,0.8,0.6],
        'A2':[np.NaN,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    },
    index=range(1,7)
)
```

[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUDnY.png)

My expected temporary state - you dont have to use:

```
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'userid':[11,12,13],
        'A1':[0.5,np.NaN,0.7],
        'A2':[1,np.NaN,np.NaN],
    },
    index=range(1,4)
)
```

The final, desired dataframe:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'userid':[11,12,13],
        'A1':[0.5,0.6,0.7],
        'A2':[1,1,1],
    },
    index=range(1,4)
)
```

[final, desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWPOs.png)

Comment: `temp_df = df.groupby(df.userid).mean()`, but how do you calculate the 'means' in `desired_df`?. For instance, how is the `0.6` produced? Do you mix the data of different users for that?

Comment: Yes, however its solved now, thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on the `userid` column and calculate the means for the answer columns to get your intermediate dataframe (`temp_df`).  Then you can just fill the missing values with the column means to get your final dataframe (`desired_df`).

```
temp_df = df.groupby('userid')[['A1', 'A2']].mean()
desired_df = temp_df.fillna(temp_df.mean())
```

`print desired_df` gives:

```
         A1   A2
userid
11      0.5  1.0
12      0.6  1.0
13      0.7  1.0
```